# Targeting datalist value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a command for when one of the following is selected. I am uncertain which ID to use to call the input value.

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers" onchange="decider()">
<option value="Internet Explorer">
<option value="Firefox">
</datalist>
<input type="submit">

<script>
function decider(){
if (document.getElementById("browser").value == "Internet Explorer"){
alert("Incorrect");}}
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not understandable nor your problem. I can try to guess and maybe even solve your problem, but I won't do it until you explain better what's your problem.

Comment: You would access the input element. That is where the value will be. Do this in the input element's change event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your example because you can't access events on datalist elements directly, and so it's better to use the related input element. I've also added listening to the oninput event onto the input element, which covers more cases of the data having changed than just onchange for an input element.

Here's the working example.

```html
<input list="browsers" name="browser" id="inputBrowsers" onchange="decider()" oninput="decider()">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
</datalist>
<input type="submit">

<script>
  function decider() {
    if (document.getElementById("inputBrowsers").value == "Internet Explorer") {
      alert("Incorrect");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here's a more advanced option, however. This more advanced option is considered better practice because it avoids a number of pitfalls associated with placing event handlers inline inside your HTML. [Scott Marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695364/scott-marcus) in the comments below has outlined the reasons why they should be avoided.

```html
<input list="browsers" name="browser" id="inputBrowsers">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
</datalist>
<input type="submit">

<script>
  var checkInput = function(event) {
    var inputElement = event.target;
    if (inputElement.value == "Internet Explorer") {
      alert("Incorrect");
    }
  };
  var element = document.getElementById("inputBrowsers");
  element.addEventListener("change", checkInput);
  element.addEventListener("input", checkInput);
</script>
```

Comment: It is really not advised to use inline event handlers as they cause global function wrappers to be created to handle the events, they cause spaghetti code and don't allow for multiple handlers to be applied. Using DOM Level 2 event registration is suggested (addEventListener).

Comment: I agree. But I wanted to keep this example as close as possible to the initial question. I'll update this.

Comment: I would not declare checkInput as a variable that has the function assigned to it (a function expression) because the declaration only will be hoisted, but the function value won't be. Instead, just make a function declaration function checkInput(){...} This will protect you if/when the function's code gets moved to perhaps a spot below the addEventListener lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the element reference correctly. getElementById() is for elements that have an ID. name is not the same thing as ID. You should modify the HTML to:

```
 <input type=text id=txtBrowserList name=txtBrowserList>
```

And then access it and code as follows:

```
 var theListControl = document.getElementById("txtBrowserList");

 theListControl.addEventListener("change", function(){
     console.log("You chose: " + theListControl.value);
     if(theListControl.value === "Internet Explorer"){
         alert("Incorrect!");
     }
 });
```